# Make a button change value of a textview

Tags: java, android, variables, button, textview

So, my friend got me to mess with android programming in android studio today.  I started making a beginner application and have had some good results.  But right now I am trying to get a button to change the value of a textview.

Here is the code for the button and the textview

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add one"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="addone"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

and here is the code that is attempting to change the value of the text view.

```
public void addone(){

    numtest+=1;
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
    t.setText(numtest);

}
```

THe program compiles and opens, but it crashes whenever i press the button.  I believe I have narrowed down the culprit to this line, but im not sure why it isnt working

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you check the logCat it helps you knows where the error come from.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An overloaded method is your problem. It is subtle, a mistake even a seasoned programmer could make. I've made it myself before.

You are calling [TextView.setText(Integer)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29). This attempts to load a string having a resource id of numtest, which does not exist.

Try this instead:

```
public void addone(View v){
    numtest+=1;
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
    t.setText(numtest+"");
}
```

This will call [TextView.setText(CharSequence)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead, which is what you're really trying to do.

Also, as Osmium USA demonstrated, your method signature is incorrect. The button pressed callback method must accept a view, and must be public.

Comment: +1 Good explanation but I think you should point out the mistake in the method signature, as well

Comment: @codeMagic fixed. It feels wrong just typing what another user did. I feel my catch was more important though... we'll see what the real answer was here soon. Bet its mine :) The compiler can't catch an accidental overloaded method call after all.

Comment: They were both just as important because both are necessary. Don't feel bad as long as you give credit if they caught something you didn't at first. No it can't catch it but it will be caught at runtime so still very important

Comment: Thanks.  That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Bigandrewgold thanks, keep up the good work. Be sure to upvote Osmium's answer.

Comment: "Be sure to upvote Osmium's answer" Look at you, spoken like a true gentleman and SO user ;) That's what this community is about...learning and respect

Answer (score 6):

When you give a layout element a function to execute, it looks for that name accepting a View (so you know what was clicked if you assign multiple elements the same click behavior in the XML).

So `addone()` must be `addone(View v)`

[From the Button Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

> In order for this to work, the method must be public and accept a View as its only parameter

William Morrison also has a good point. You should make that number a String either by what he did or use the Integer Class:

```
t.setText(Integer(numtest).toString());
```

or

```
t.setText(numtest+"");
```

Comment: I think this isn't the problem, however thank you for catching the method signature definition. I'd have missed it if it weren't for you.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison this isn't the only problem but it won't find the method without the proper signature

Comment: +1 Good explanation of the problem. You may just want to include links in the docs for future reference so people know exactly where to look for these things

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
public void addone(View view){
    switch(view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button3:
            numtest+=1;
            TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
            t.setText(Integer.toString(numtest));
        break;
    }
}
```